# Apache Spark: Why I can't use broadcast var defined in a global object

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is a simplified example to show my concern. This example contains 3 files with 3 objects, depending on spark 1.6.1.

```
//file globalObject.scala 
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast 

object globalObject { 
  var br_value: Broadcast[Map[Int, Double]] = null 
} 


//file someFunc.scala 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD 

object someFunc { 
  def go(rdd: RDD[Int])(implicit sc: SparkContext): Array[Int] = { 
    rdd.map(i => { 
      val acc = globalObject.br_value.value 
      if(acc.contains(i)) { 
        i + 1 
      } else { 
        i 
      } 
    }).take(100) 
 } 
} 

//testMain.scala 
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 

object testMain { 
  def bootStrap()(implicit sc:SparkContext): Unit = { 
    globalObject.br_value = sc.broadcast(Map(1->2, 2->3, 4->5)) 
  } 

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    lazy val appName = getClass.getSimpleName.split("\\$").last 
    implicit val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)) 
    val datardd = sc.parallelize(Range(0, 200), 200) 
      .flatMap(i => Range(0, 1000)) 

    bootStrap() 
    someFunc.go(datardd).foreach(println) 

  } 
}
```

When I run this code on cluster, it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at someFunc$$anonfun$go$1.apply$mcII$sp(someFunc.scala:7) 
        at someFunc$$anonfun$go$1.apply(someFunc.scala:6) 
        at someFunc$$anonfun$go$1.apply(someFunc.scala:6) 
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) 
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312) 
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) 
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) 
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
```

Apparently, the data is not successfully broadcasted. I met this problem when I was refactoring my code these days. I want different scala objects to share a same broadcast variable. But now here it is. Pretty confusing now, as to my understanding driver uses pointer to indicate broadcast variable. Calling broadcast variable shouldn't be restricted to the same code scope.

Correct me if I am wrong. And what's the proper way to share broadcast var among scala objects ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Code in `map` is serialized and executed on each node. `val acc = globalObject.br_value.value` uses the node's `globalObject.br_value`. But of course that's still `null`; you only assign it on the driver. You could make your code close over the broadcast variable by pulling it out of the lambda:

```
val br_value = globalObject.br_value
rdd.map(i => { 
  val acc = br_value.value 
  if(acc.contains(i)) { 
    i + 1 
  } else { 
    i 
  } 
}).take(100)
```

Comment: I meet the same problem, but still have no idea why it happens. does `map` serialized at runtime? if so, the globalObject.br_value is assigned before the serialization,  the node's reference to it should be the newest non-null value. am I missing something?